# What is the difference between Section and Stack in Blade?

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade

We can use a `section` to define some HTML and then `yield` that somewhere else.

So why do we have stacks?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks

It's doing exactly the same thing with different keywords, but has fewer options (No inheritance).

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush

<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->

    @stack('scripts')
</head>
```

Can be done with section:

```
@section('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endsection

<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->

    @yield('scripts')
</head>
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but the difference is not only semantically, but in behaviour as well. 
With *@push* you *append* as many times as needed to a stack, while (by default) you may fill *@section* only *once* in your views.
In some situations this comes in handy when you need to add content from different locations across your template files or in loops:

index.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')

...  

@for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)

  @push('test-push')
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Push {{ $i }}
    </script>
  @endpush

  @section('test-section')
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Section {{ $i }}
    </script>
  @endsection

@endfor
```

master.blade.php

```
    @stack('test-push')
    @yield('test-section')
</body>
```

result:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Push 0
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    // Push 1
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    // Push 2
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Section 0
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: What about `@section@append` ? I believe they have same behavior.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that `you may fill @section only once in your views`. This was causing super a weird bug, switched to @stack and it now works as it should

Comment: @fgilio glad it still helped :)

Answer (score 12):

Stack is someway appropriate for scripts , with stack you can Append as much as you need .

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
 @endpush
```

Append …

```
<script>
@stack('scripts')
</script>
```

As you can see the script's stack will be appended under the script tag of example js. So you can push special scripts for each view.

Comment: If you just have wrote the js inside the child view to be esecuted, why push that code to render in the main view? I don't understand exacly the utility...

Answer (score 7):

```
@section - You can add your js css once.
@stack   - Push js, aand css into stack (page) many times.
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.